# C# to VB.net conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can someone please help me convert this to VB.net:

```
HttpPostedFile jpeg_image_upload = Request.Files["Filedata"];
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim jpeg_image_upload As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files("Filedata")
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't like the "Request" part. It says "'Request' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level" and a suggested solution is to "Change 'Request' to 'HTTPRequest'"

Comment: The original C# code almost certainly lived in the code-behind for an ASPX page. Does your VB code do the same?

Comment: No, this is a webservice VB.net application

Comment: Do you have `Imports System.Web` in your class file?

Comment: Yes I do. I've gotten post data from another post call using "HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("txtUserName")" but this is SWFUpload sending the post data, and the original code I posted was the C# code they said would work, and I need it in VB.net

Comment: I'm confused about the context.  Why are you using `Request` in a "web service VB.net application?"  Is this REST or SOAP?

Comment: REST or SOAP? I'm not sure what those acronyms mean?

Comment: You will have to edit your original question or post a new one with more context than you've given here in order for me or anyone else here to help.

Answer (score 0):

it will be:

```
Dim jpeg_image_upload as HttpPostedFile
jpeg_image_upload = Request.Files("Filedata")
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't like the "Request" part. It says "'Request' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level" and a suggested solution is to "Change 'Request' to 'HTTPRequest'"

Comment: Are you sure you have Imported System.Web.. it seems its not available for use in your context